# Crash in SwiftUI when selecting and deselecting List

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am seeing a crash in SwiftUI List and it is related to the selection & deselection (on iOS 16.x).
Wanted to check if this is an issue with framework & if there are workarounds for it?

Steps to crash.
Select any row between 2-5,
Tap on update button (which updated the data source of the list).
Try to select first row (only available row) & the app crashes.

import SwiftUI

struct New: View {

```
@State var listItems: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
@State var selection: String?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Update") {
            updateDataSource()
        }
        
        List (selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
}

func updateDataSource() {
    selection = nil
    listItems = ["1"]
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You should add the relevant code to your question

Comment: If you are going to be changing your data source like that, you should use an identifiable model, and not rely on `\.self`. The issue is the "1" you replaced the array of string with is getting confused with the "1" in the original array. They identify as the same thing ( and yes, they are both "1", but they are not the same "1") and that is confusing SwiftUI. See [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/). Essentially, if you are using `\.self` as the `id`, you are most likely doing it wrong, especially with a mutable value.

Answer (score 0):

Assign explicit id to the list and change it when list changes. This will cause list state reset:

```
import SwiftUI

struct New: View {

@State var listId: UUID = UUID()
@State var listItems: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
@State var selection: String?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Update") {
            updateDataSource()
        }
        
        List (selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
        .id(listId)
    }
    .padding()
}

func updateDataSource() {
    selection = nil
    listItems = ["1"]
    listId = UUID()
}
}
```